# JPA TypedQuery: Parameter value element did not match expected type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA 2.0 and having following code in DAO layer:

```
public void test() {
  String key = "status";
  String[] statuses = {"A", "B"};
  List<TestTable> result = find(key, statuses);
}

public List<TestTable> find(String key, Object valueArr) {
  String sql = "SELECT nd FROM TestTable nd WHERE nd." + key + " IN :" + key;
  TypedQuery<TestTable> query = entityManager.createQuery(sql, TestTable.class);
  query.setParameter(key, Arrays.asList(valueArr))//***Error Line***
  return query.getResultList();
}
```

In the above Error Line it throws following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [[Ljava.lang.String;@cbe5bc] did not match expected type [java.lang.String]
```

Why it expected type is String whereas actually it is String[] ? Please help!

Note: This is the extracted and simplified code from the generic routine I cannot change the 'Object valueArr' to String[] because its being used for others...

Comment: why are you having using key in two places in the query? Doesn't look quite right

Answer (score 2):

You've got a variable of type `Object`, and you're calling [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-). That means you've effectively called:

```
List<Object> values = Arrays.asList(new Object[] {valueArr});
```

So you're creating a list of a single element, where that element is an array. That's not what you want... you want a `List<Object>` with as many elements as you had to start with. The simplest way to do that is to change your parameter type:

```
public List<TestTable> find(String key, Object[] values)

...

query.setParameter(key, Arrays.asList(values));
```

Comment: Great catch! infact I cannot change the Object parameter to Object[], probabely I will try with: "Arrays.asList((Object[]) valueArr)", but not sure will it work with primitive arrays e.g. int[] or not ?

Comment: @user3568038: If you can't change the parameter type but you always actually *require* the value to be an `Object[]`, then just cast inside the method.

Comment: what about primitive arrays e.g. int[] ?

Comment: @Chandan Well `Arrays.asList` won't work for them anyway, so you'll need to work out a different approach. You could use `Integer[]` though.

Comment: Thank Jon for the help and finding bug. I've correct it by following way: hopefully now it works for all type of elements :) ::
public static List<Object> toCollection(Object array) {
  int length = Array.getLength(array);
  List<Object> l = new ArrayList<Object>(length);
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   l.add(Array.get(array, i));
  }
  return l;
 }